# Selecting items from a hash based on sub-hash values

Tags: ruby

I have the following JSON output from an API:

```
{
  "Objects": [
    {
      "FieldValues": [
        {
          "Field": {
            "Name": "Nuix Field"
          },
          "Value": "Primary Date"
        },
        {
          "Field": {
            "Name": "Field Type"
          },
          "Value": {
            "Name": "Nuix"
          }
        },
        {
          "Field": {
            "Name": "Field Category"
          },
          "Value": {
            "Name": "Generic"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to select all `Objects` where "Field" has a "Name" of "Field Type" and it's "Value" has a "Name" of "Nuix".

This is my attempt, but I feel like there is a better way to do it?

```
json = JSON.parse(response)
        results = []
            json["Objects"].each do |obj|
                obj["FieldValues"].each do |fv|
                    if fv["Field"]["Name"] == "Field Type" && fv["Value"]["Name"] == "Nuix"
                        results << obj
                    end
                end
            end
```

Comment: Because `FieldValues` and `Objects` are an array, there be no much difference from execution point of view, you still need to loop through all field value objects. What you mean by "better way"? What improvements you are looking for?

Comment: Your structure has both a hash for `"Name"` and sometimes not a hash but a string?

Comment: First entry has `"Value": "Primary Date"` while others have `"Value": { "Name": ... }`.

Comment: Your hash has one key-value pair, the key being `:Objects`, the value being an array containing a single value, a hash containing a single key-value pair, the key being `:FieldValues`, the value being an array of hashes. If `h` is your hash, let `arr = h[:Objects][0][:FieldValues]`.  Do you wish to return an array containing those elements `g` of `arr` (hashes), for which `g[:Field][:Name]` equals `"Field Type"` and `g[:Value][:Name]` equals `"Nuix"`?

Comment: Is there a more "Ruby" like way to do this, i.e a one liner? I'm coming from C#, so I could typically use LINQ in this type of situation to get a neat, one line solution. @tadman - yes that's correct, that is how the API returns results. I've stripped out some of the other content in the hash but that is how its returned.

Comment: Perhaps something with [`slice`](https://rubyapi.org/3.0/o/hash#method-i-slice), as in `fv["Field"].slice("Field", "Name") == needle` where that second part is defined like `needle = { "Field" => "Field Type", "Name" => "Nuix" }`.

Comment: This would be a lot less clunky if you had lower-case key names and imported using `symbolize_names: true`, so then it's just `fv[:field]` and `slice(:field, :name)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is not to loop all `FieldValues` but only until expected one is found with the `any?` method.
Then you can simplify code with `select` method, which will create new array with only "satisfied" objects.

```
objects_with_required_fields = json.fetch("Objects", []).select do |obj|
  obj.fetch("FieldValues", []).any? do |fv|
    name = fv.dig("Field", "Name")
    value = fv["Value"]

    name == "Field Type" && value.is_a?(Hash) && value["Name"] == "Nuix"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more minimal Ruby solution:

```rb
json = JSON.parse(response, symbolize_names: true)

target = [ 'Field Type', 'Value' ]

# For each of the entries in Objects...
results = json[:Objects].flat_map do |obj|
  # ...filter out those that...
  obj[:FieldValues].select do |fv|
    # ...match the target criteria.
    [ fv.dig(:Field, :Name), fv[:Value] ] == target
  end
end
```

Where that uses symbolized keys and just filters through an array of arrays looking for matching entries, then returns those in one (flat) array.